# Pentaho PDI on Ubuntu 18

Tags: extract

I have Pentaho setup and running on Windows 10, I am planning to migrate to Ubuntu. Has anyone setup Pentaho on Ubuntu 18.04? If yes, what is the configuration you are using? Pentaho documentation says mentions Ubuntu 14 and 16 to be used and are there any issues in particular on Ubuntu 18?

Comment: Ubuntu 18?  No such release, are you talking about *snap* based Ubuntu Core 18 (and likewise Ubuntu Core 16...)   Ubuntu uses *yy* only with *snap* based releases, all desktop & server releases are *yy.mm* in format (though they can use *snaps* too, but aren't limited to *snaps*)

Comment: It will work on 18.04 but not on 20.04. There is a dependency for `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0` and that got dropped after 18.04 You can for instance use https://piezobytes.blogspot.com/2019/05/install-pentaho-data-integration-on-ubuntu.html as an installation guide.